# jQuery: Loading ajax URL as variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firebug

In the past I've always used the callback function in the getJson function to handle the fetched data, but as I want to save the fetched data as a variable, to prevent it from being fetched again, I've run in to some strange issues. When trying the following code out, I start getting this error in firebug; `Permission denied for <http://localhost> to get property XMLHttpRequest.channel`

Am I doing it wrong trying to do this without the callback function?

```
function fetch(){
    var returndata = $.getJSON( 'http://localhost/api/get/1' );

    formatDataset(returndata);
}

function formatDataset(data){
    var row = '';

    $.each(data, function(){
        row += this.name + '<br>';
    });

    $('#myDiv').html(row);
}
```

Comment: no credit for me , i suggested the fix right, just kidding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're correct in your question where you ask about the callback. The $.getJSON function returns the XMLHttpRequest not the data. So try something like:

```
var returndata;
function fetch(){
    if (!returndata) {
        $.getJSON( 'http://localhost/api/get/1', function(data) {
            returndata = data; 
            formatDataset(returndata);
        });
        return;
    }
    formatDataset(returndata);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong in your code

```
var returndata = $.getJSON( 'http://localhost/api/get/1' );
```

ajax is asyncronous call , so it will start the process and goes on , you can not use that as a return type.

if you want to get things done , write the code in the succcess handler oof getjson